# how to tokenize/parse/search&replace document by font AND font style in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: parsing, scripting, tokenize, libreoffice, writer

I need to update a bilingual dictionary written in Writer by first parsing all entries into their parts e.g.

- main word (font 1, bold)
- foreign equivalent transliterated (font 1, italic)
- foreign equivalent (font 2, bold)
- part of speech (font 1, italic)

Each line of the document is the main word followed by the parts listed above, each separated by a space or punctuation.

I need to automate the process of walking through the whole file, line by line, and place a delimiter between each part, ignoring spaces and punctuation, so I can mass import it into a Calc file. In other words, "each part" is a sequence of character (ignoring spaces and punctuation) that have the same font AND font-style.

I have tried the standard Search&Replace feature, and AltSearch extension, but neither are able to complete the task. The main problem is I am not able to write a search query that says:

**Find:** consecutive characters with the same font AND font_style, ignore spaces and punctuation

**Replace:** term found above + "delimiter"

Any suggestions how I can write a script for this, or if an existing tool can solve the problem?

Thanks!

Pseudo code for desired effect:

```
var delimiter = "|"

Go to beginning of document

While not end of document do:
     var $currLine = get line from doc
     var $currChar = get next character which is not space or punctuation;
     var $font = currChar.font
     var $font_style - currChar.font_style (e.g. bold, italic, normal)

     While not end of line do:
         $currChar = next character which is not space or punctuation;

          if (currChar.font != $font || currChar.font_style != $font_style) { // font or style has changed
               print $delimiter

               $font = currChar.font
               $font_style - currChar.font_style (e.g. bold, italic, normal)
          }
     end While

end While
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are tips for each of the things your pseudocode does.

First, the easiest way to move line by line is with the [TextViewCursor](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/TextViewCursor), although it is slow.  Notice the XLineCursor section.  For the while loop, `oVC.`[goDown()](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/view/XViewCursor.html#goDown) will return false when the end of the document is reached.  (`oVC` is our variable for the TextViewCursor).

Get each character by calling `oVC.goRight(0, False)` to deselect followed by `oVC.goRight(1, True)` to select.  Then the selected value is obtained by `oVC.getString()`.  To ignore space and punctuation, perhaps use python's [isalnum()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) or the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module.

To determine the font of the character, call `oVC.getPropertyValue(attr)`.  Values for `attr` could simply be  `CharAutoStyleName` and `CharStyleName` to check for any changes in formatting.

Or grab a list of specific properties such as `'CharFontFamily', 'CharFontFamilyAsian', 'CharFontFamilyComplex', 'CharFontPitch', 'CharFontPitchAsian'` etc.  Character properties are described at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Text/Formatting.

To insert the delimiter into the text: `oVC.getText().insertString(oVC, "|", 0)`.

[This python code from github](https://github.com/jkornelsen/OOLingTools/blob/master/LinguisticTools/pythonpath/lingt/access/writer/textsearch.py) shows how to do most of these things, although you'll need to read through it to find the relevant parts.

Alternatively, instead of using the LibreOffice API, unzip the `.odt` file and parse `content.xml` with a script.

Comment: Unzipping the .odt and pulling out the .xml file was a helpful suggestion! I didn't realize .odt was a zip format.